# Flutter app is crashing when trying to creating account with email and password

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

This is my code for creating an account but when email id is already registered app crashing and my try catch method don't catch it.
How to solve this issue?

```
void careteAccount() async {
if (in_email.text.trim().length > 0 && in_password.text.trim().length > 0) {
  try {
    //   FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: "+919656936681", codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {}, codeSent: (String verificationId, int forceResendingToken) {}, timeout: null, verificationCompleted: (FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {}, verificationFailed: (AuthException error) {});

    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: in_email.value.text.trim(), password: in_password.value.text.trim())
            .catchError((e){
              print(e.toString());
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: e.toString(),
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
        timeInSecForIos: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        textColor: Colors.white);
            })
            .then((u){
              if(u!=null?u.email!=null?true:false:false){
                print("account created "+u.email);
              }else{
                print("account creatin failed");
              }
            });
    print("create accound in ${user.email}");
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: e.toString(),
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
        timeInSecForIos: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        textColor: Colors.white);
    print('Error $e');
  }
} else {
  print("login called and countroler is null");
}}
```

error message "The given password is invalid. [ Password should be at least 6 characters ]"

[image: firebase flutter auth error]

I need to cath the error programiticly and not like above image

> > D/        ( 8896): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb40f0c90, tid 8923 D/EGL_emulation( 8896):
> >     eglMakeCurrent: 0xb42bc4c0: ver 2 0 W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 8896):
> >     [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:
> >     com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@3b1fc27b

Error when successfully account is created

```
I/flutter ( 9012): account created milla@gmail.com
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'className' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: className
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      serializeProcedure (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/utils.dart:99:29)
#2      FrontendCompiler.compileExpression (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:482:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compileExpression (package:frontend_server/server.dart:62:22)
#4      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:797:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#8      _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
#9      _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
#10     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:268:11)
#11     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:154:13)
#12     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:129:5)
#13     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:189:5)
#14     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
#15     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
#18     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:68:11)
#19     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)
#20     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:268:11)
#21     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:273:7)
#22     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:348:20)
#23     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:341:5)
#24     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:86:18)
#25     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:120:24)
#26     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1314:10)
#27     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:336:11)
#28     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:263:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, password must be at least 6 characters.

Comment: i need to catch the error programiticly not like crash error

Comment: i dont understand the soluction

Comment: can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

For make code more safety and secure from throw exception you must check if code throw it when create auth account in firebase or login also

for example use this in you state add this method in your `FirebaseAuthUtil class` as example

```
static Future<dynamic> createEmailAndPassword(String email,String pass) async{

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


    try {
      AuthResult result =await mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass);

      FirebaseUser userFirebase = await mAuth.currentUser();
      if (userFirebase != null && result.user.uid == userFirebase.uid) {
        return userFirebase;
      } else {
        return PlatformException(code: "-1", message: "error assign uid");
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      debugPrint("ex :${ex.code}");
      return ex;
    }
```

and call above method from you signUp page

```
dynamic result = FirebaseAuthUtil.createEmailAndPassword(email, pass);

    if(result is FirebaseUser ){
      // create account is success
    }else if(result is PlatformException){
      debugPrint("ereor signUp :${result.code}");
    }
```